# tinymce dialog with ajax content

Tags: jquery, ajax, dialog, tinymce

I want to create a TinyMCE plugin for my CMS.

I want to make a dialog which get its content by ajax (image list + ajaxuploader). If the user selects/uploads a image the image should be pasted into the editor.

I need a solution for: get the ajax (jquery) content into the dialog and get the selected image to the editor.

Does someone know a good example/tutorial?

Sorry for my odd english.

Comment: Hint: `$('iframe').contents().find('body').html('<content to append>')` and you need to provide what is your attempt to solve the problem. No one would provide you readymade code.

Answer (score 2):

i'm using sth similar for custom `tinymce 4+` plugins.

Right now i use the following:

1. On plugin button click (or menu item or whatever)
2. Set `editor.setProgressState(1)` (in progress)
3. Do the ajax before opening dialog with `tinymce.util.XHR` (similar to jquery `ajax`)
4. on `XHR` return, set `editor.setProgressState(0)` (complete), then open the dialog with the ajax content
5. on dialog close (or image selection) get the selected image and update editor with `editor.selection.setContent(..)`

This is how the included `image` tinymce plugin works as well.

Alternatively one can just open a custom `iframe` dialog (with the necessary `jquery` libraries or whatever) and do all that inside the dialog itself (as a mini application).

This is what was done with the custom plugins but i wanted to use more tinymce native methods.

**sample plugin code**

```
tinymce.PluginManager.requireLangPack('my_plugin');
tinymce.PluginManager.add('my_plugin', function( editor, url ) {
    var _ = tinymce.util.I18n.translate,
        plugin_url = url + ('/' === url.slice(-1) ? '' : '/')
    ;

    function insert_or_replace( content ) {
        editor.focus( );
        if ( editor.selection )
            editor.selection.setContent( content );
        else
            editor.insertContent( content );
    };

    function buildListItems(inputList, itemCallback, startItems) {
        function appendItems(values, output) {
            output = output || [];

            tinymce.each(values, function(item) {
                var menuItem = {text: item.text || item.title, value: ""};
                itemCallback(menuItem, item);
                output.push(menuItem);
            });

            return output;
        }

        return appendItems(inputList, startItems || []);
    }

    function ajax( ajaxurl, cb ) {
        return function( ) {
            editor.setProgressState( 1 ); // Show progress
            tinymce.util.XHR.send({
                url: ajaxurl,
                success: function( res ) {
                    editor.setProgressState( 0 ); // Hide progress
                    cb( !!res ? tinymce.util.JSON.parse( res ) : res );
                }
            });
        };
    };

    function popup( data ) {
        // Open editor window
        var listBox, win = editor.windowManager.open({
            title: _('Insert'),
            resizable : true,
            maximizable : true,
            width: 400,
            height: 300,
            body: [
            {
                type: 'listbox',
                name: 'my_control',
                label: _('Insert'),
                tooltip: _('Select item'),
                values: buildListItems(data, function( item, datum ) {
                    item.value = datum;
                    item.text = datum.title;
                }),
                onPostRender: function( ){
                    listBox = this;
                }
            }
            ],
            buttons: [
                { text: _('Insert'), subtype: 'primary', onclick: function( ){
                    var selected = listBox.value( );
                    if ( !!selected )
                        insert_or_replace( '[my-shortcode id="'+selected.id+'" title="'+selected.title+'"]' )
                    win.close( );
                }},
                { text: _('Cancel'), onclick: 'close' }
            ]
        });
    };

    editor.addButton('my_button', {
        title: _('Sample Button'),
        icon: 'my-icon',
        onclick: ajax(editor.settings.my_plugin.ajaxurl, popup)
    });

    editor.addMenuItem('my_menu', {
        icon: 'my-icon',
        text: _('Sample Menu'),
        context: 'insert',
        onclick: ajax(editor.settings.my_plugin.ajaxurl, popup)
    });
});
```